# How do you change the color of a UIButton when you are pressing it?

Tags: swift, colors, uibutton

I am wondering how can you can change the color of a UIButton when it is pressed. By default, a UIButton has a faded blue when you press it. How do I change this from faded to, for example purple, when I press it. How do I do this in Swift 4? Is there some sort of property I can change?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

use this extension for button:

```
extension UIButton {
  func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, forState controlState: UIControl.State) {
    let colorImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)).image { _ in
      color.setFill()
      UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)).fill()
    }
    setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: controlState)
  }
}
```

and simply usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        button.setBackgroundColor(.red, forState: .normal)
        button.setBackgroundColor(.blue, forState: .highlighted)

        view.addSubview(button)
    }
```

hope this make you smile :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTitleColor(_:for:)` to set the title color (the first parameter) differently for the `.normal` and the `.highlighted` state (the second parameter).

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor

Comment: You probably have a `system` button. You might need to make this a `custom` button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `setBackgroundImage` function to archive that:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "PURPLE_IMAGE"), for: .highlighted)
```

You can set image for `highlighted`, `selected`, `disable`...etc

I know your question is to change the highlight background color, not the background image, but unfortunately it doesn't seems to have a direct way to do it. So my work around is to programmatically create an image of that color for the same effect (you may want to put it in UIImage extension):

```
let rect = CGRect(point: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
context!.fill(rect)
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `UIButton` background color with click you can simply use `backgroundColor` property as shown below:

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { //sender type should be UIButton
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
}
```

and if you want to set title color on click you can use `setTitleColor` property as shown below:

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.purple, for: .highlighted)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .backgroundColor for set Color; var button_isActive for button press, UIView.animate

```
 var button_isActive: Bool = false 

 @IBAction func btn_Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if button_isActive {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        }
    }
    button_isActive = !button_isActive
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: Even after setting the background color

```
btn.backgroundColor = .red
```

The color changing was not displaying, took a while to figure out that I need to change uibutton configuration from "Filled" to "Default"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for button color change

```
@IBAction func btnPress(_ sender: UIButton) { 
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.yourButton.backgroundColor = .purple
  }
}
```